# How to use isosurface() for images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I am new to `matlab`. I have few binary images, as shown below, which I have to display with `isosurfaces` as a 3d object. I could not understand what input I need to pass to this function, when I have some images. I am referring this [documentation](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html).

I have total 22 images which are slightly diffrent from this image:

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what surface you want to display, `isosurfaces` works on volume data, i.e. a 3d dataset, not a 2d image. is it possible that the 22 images are slices of a volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 22 images are all images from the same volume, you can concatenate them into a 3D array with the dimensions of `[nRows, nCols, 22]`. How you do this really depends upon the format your data is currently in.

You can then pass this 3D matrix (`images`) *directly* to `isosurface` along with an isovalue (I'll assume 1 for demonstration purposes);

```
FV = isosurface(images, 1);
```

Comment: It's required that `images` must have values greater than `isovalue` which is `1` in this case. Because images were binary, I just executed `images = images * 2` where `images` is of size `512x512x22`.